# Best Method to Grab Specific Keys(Properties) from Nested Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested, key

What is the best method to get specific keys (i.e. "longName") from nested objects with this structure:

```
const routes = {
   "14094": {
      "routeId": 14094,
      "shortName": "2",
      "longName": "Route 1"
   },
   "14095": {
      "routeId": 14095,
      "shortName": "7",
      "longName": "Route 2"
   },
   "14096": {
      "routeId": 14096,
      "shortName": "42",
      "longName": "Route 3"
   },
   "14097": {
      "routeId": 14097,
      "shortName": "57",
      "longName": "Route 4"
   },
```

I have tried to console.log(routes[1]), dot notation, and other methods but I am not having any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure here is an object of objects. So you can access the `longName` key-value pair in this manner: `routes[14094].longName` which should return `Route 1`, based on the original data.

If you want to get all the `longName` values for each object, you can use a for loop like this:

```
for (const key in routes) {
   console.log(routes[key].longName)
   }
```

You need to first reference the object using the "outer" key (e.g. 14094), then you can use dot notation for the keys in the "inner" object.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the feedback and it is very helpful.